# Expanding a top navigation bar to full width of page

Tags: html, css, navigation

I would like a topbar navigation, similar to one that you see with Foundation. The problem i'm having is that i've set margins for the page and dont know how to override them?

So for most of page (body) I need these margins but for the top bar i'd like it extending the full width of the browser.

Here's the code:

```
body {
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #000000;
background-color: white;
margin: 0em 6.5em 3.5em;

#nav ul {

width: 100%;
background-color: #212121;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
text-align: left;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  height: inherit;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #212121;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
 background: #212121;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
 #nav ul li ul li { 
   background: #212121; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
}
 #nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #212121; }
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Html:

```
    <body>
  <div id="nav">
  <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Venue</li>
  <li>Events</li>
  <li>Stalls
    <ul>
      <li>Food</li>
      <li>Arts & Crafts</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is foundation? You haven't closed the style rule for body, is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the following css for the header,

```
#nav{
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

It's take the nav out of normal flow and stretch it from left to right.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5D5eD/32/)

If you set `position:fixed; width:100%;` then the header will be taken out of the normal flow and will be positioned relative to the window. It'll stay where it is even if the user scrolls down the page.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using absolute positioning, you can just use negative margins for the `#nav` like this:

```
#nav {
  margin-left:-6.5em;
  margin-right:-6.5em;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N9wDB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fixed` positioning for the navigation bar you want at the top of your page.

```
#nav {
    min-width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Adding a `min-width` of 100% should ensure the navigation bar stretches across the width of your page. Setting `top` and `left` to zero, in conjunction with `position:fixed`, would anchor the nav div to the top-left.

Comment: This will set the header relative to window, if will stay where it is even if the user scrolls down.

Comment: @TilwinJoy, yeah, I'd assumed that was what the asker wanted with their navigation bar.

Comment: @DhruvKapoor Yeah maybe, i'm not sure what he meant by 'foundation', please make an edit to you're post so that i can remove the downvote..